# "names the constructor, not the type" in G++ 4.4.7

Tags: c++, gcc

I have the following simple C++ code:

```
#include <cstdio>

class A
{
public:
    A(int y) : x(y) {}
    A& operator=(const A& rhs);
    int x;
};

A::A& A::operator=(const A& rhs) { this->x = rhs.x; return *this; }

int main(int, char**)
{
    A a1(5);
    A a2(4);

    printf("a2.x == %d\n", a2.x);

    a2 = a1;

    printf("a2.x == %d\n", a2.x);

    return 0;
}
```

Line 11, where the definition of `A`'s `operator=()` function is at, is malformed...or, at least, I believe so. As expected, G++ 4.7.4, as well as every newer version of GCC that I've tried, throws the following error:

```
main.cpp:11:1: error: ‘A::A’ names the constructor, not the type
```

Oddly, though, G++ 4.4.7 compiles this program successfully, with no warnings, and even prints 4 and 5 as would be expected if line 11 were written correctly (i.e. with just `A&` instead of `A::A&`).

Can someone help me decipher what exactly is going on there with G++ 4.4.7? Is this just a bug in that release (albeit an extremely old one, and shame on us for still using it)? I'd think the standard would explicitly state how the `operator=()` function must be declared and defined.

Comment: There is no shame in using an old compiler to support a legacy codebase. It's damn hard to get funding to upgrade the tool chain for a working product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a [related bug in g++](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11764). It was fixed in version 4.5.0, so 4.4.7 still has it.

Here is the bug description:

> cc1plus does not implement the class name injection correctly.
>   In particular the snipped below should be rejected on the basis that
>   A::A does not name a type (it designates a constructor)
>
> ```
> struct A { };
>
> int main()
> {
>     A::A a;       // should be an ERROR
> }
> ```

Although the symptoms of this bug are not identical to what you describe, in both cases the compiler treats `A::A` as a type name, when it actually names a constructor. I am pretty certain that the two behaviors have the same root cause, which is poor implementation of scope resolution prior to version 4.5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on dasblinkenlight's [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44295729/5689220)--the C++03 standard explicitly outlaws his and my code in `[class.qual]`:

> If the *nested-name-specifier* nominates a class C, and the name
>   specified after the *nested-name-specifier*, when looked up in C, is the
>   injected-class-name of C (clause 9), the name is instead considered to
>   name the constructor of class C. Such a constructor name shall be used
>   only in the *declarator-id* of a constructor definition that appears
>   outside of the class definition. [*Example:*
>
> ```
> struct A { A(); };
> struct B: public A { B(); };
>
> A::A() { }
> B::B() { }
>
> B::A ba; // object of type A
> A::A a;  // error, A::A is not a type name
> ```
>
> *—end example*]